# How to Identify the WSP of the deploy webparts

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, solution-package

I have a requirement, where i need to identify the wsp to which the webpart belongs.

**Scenario:** We are migrating from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. Existing Sharepoint has multiple WSPs and each WSP has multiple webparts. Problem is client does not have any documentation around the code. All we got from therir side the list of web parts which they need and which they do not, by showing us on the pages?

Long way is to open all solutions and find out the webparts, but is there a easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename solution.wsp to solution.cab and you can view the content of the wsp. That way you can find web parts, features and everything else deployed to a farm.

To ensure you have the installed solution, download them from the farm directly using this script:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("solution.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\temp\solution.wsp")
```

Comment: There are more than 100 wsp's deployed and only a very few needed. This way i will go from WSP to webpart, Is there a way i could track WSP from webpart?

Comment: Usually developers have a tendency to name solutions to what they contain, or their action. That's the only way, since there are no shortcuts here. You can of course download all in a loop, and rename all in a second loop. That way you can search for the webpart in all solutions at the same time.